# HOGDescriptor::computeGradient using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I try to compute gradient map using HOGDescriptor.
My code:

```
HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.compute(faceROI,ders,Size(32,32),Size(0,0),locs);
Mat grad;
Mat sec;
hog.computeGradient(frame_gray, grad, angleofs);

imshow("1", frame_gray);
imshow("2", grad); //here program fails: Unhandled exception at memory location
imshow("3", angleofs); //grad.data = "". Why??
```

I cant find goot examples of using HOGDescriptor::computeGradient.

Help please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To visualize OpenCv's HOGDescriptor::Calculate(..), use [this](http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/doku.php?id=public:hog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization), it's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

imshow("2", grad); fails because imshow expects that grad image is a 1, 3 or 4 channel image whereas it is a 2 channel image.

First channel contains the gradient in x direction whereas the second channel contains the gradient in y. You should split the channels in two images to visualize them:

```
Mat grad_channel[2];
split(grad, grad_channel);
imshow("grad_x", grad_channel[0]);
imshow("grad_y", grad_channel[1]);
```

Best